# Replicate local user policies between PC's

Tags: windows, user-management, mmc

I used the Local Policy Editor Management Console that applies local policies to a specific user on a Windows 10 PC.

After saving the new policies, I want to replicate it to other PCs.

When I opened it on another PC with the same user, I got an error saying that there was no mapping between the account names and security id.

How can I replicate those local policies for multiple PCs?

Comment: `error saying that there was no mapping between the account names and security id.` Correct. Windows 101: user accounts on different computers are not the same, even if the username is the same. That is why Active Directory was created, to have a central store of user accounts that would be recognized on all computers. Active Directory also has Group Policy, which is convenient for transparently replicating Group Policy to computers.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use an AD with this network. There's simply none.

Comment: Consider scheduled tasks or a script on a file share in the network as alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found [PolicyPlus](https://github.com/Fleex255/PolicyPlus) to be the best tool for my needs.

I began by importing a default user policy into PolicyPlus, subsequently refining specific policy settings. After making these adjustments, I proceeded to export the modified policies into a file and stored it on an external drive.

For each computer, I created a limited user account and imported the tailored user policy using PolicyPlus. By importing the previously saved file, I saved the modifications to user policies.

To complete the process, I utilized the MMC editor to craft a new snap-in designed for the user's local policy. This customized snap-in was saved and seamlessly integrated into the user policy configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea, but..if the policy got corresponding registry value, then...

Take the two Registry.pol file under :\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\ [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/policy/registry-policy-file-format)

> The Group Policy Object Editor stores registry-based configuration
> settings in two Registry.pol files, stored in folders under the
> :\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\ folder. One file contains
> computer settings and the other file contains user settings. The Group
> Policy Object Editor saves the settings to these files on exit, and
> imports the settings on startup.

Better idea to manage your computer;

Create a GPO that target that computer and make it apply to other computers you want.

By copying the .pol file you fall like it was on older system like NT4 with poledit to make policies.. It's a way back to a nightmare for many tech that lived that period IMO, but welcome to the boat if you use that method I guess.